# select case return error

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get 'Problem' or 'OK' from this script?

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN COUNT (1) >0
             THEN 'problem'
          ELSE 'ok'
       END AS durum
     FROM (SELECT
    PBillingCode, OfferingSubTypeID
    INTO #Coklu_Basit_Sunu
    FROM 
        TOfferingBase
    GROUP BY 
        OfferingSubTypeID, PBillingCode
    ORDER BY PBillingCode

SELECT
    PBillingCode Faturalama_Kodu, 'Yandaki Faturalama Kodu Hem Çoklu Sunu Hem de Basit Sunuda Kullanılmıştır.' Açıklama
    FROM
        #Coklu_Basit_Sunu
    GROUP BY
        PBillingCode
    HAVING
    COUNT(PBillingCode) >=2

DROP TABLE #Coklu_Basit_Sunu)
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The query makes no sense.

Comment: Your Question is not clear and does not have enough information. Please add more details to the Question, Like your Sample input, Expected output and the Error or the Result that you are getting

Comment: There's a lot of problems with your SQL as well. For example, you outer query is selecting from a Sub Query with an `INTO` Clause. There are, also, 2 `SELECT` statements in the subquery and then a DROP. I think I know, from the SQL, what the OP wants, but I'm not posting a Crystal Ball answer out there.

Answer (score 0):

Is not it awesome that we can actually speak Programmish instead of English or Turkish?

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
    SELECT   PBillingCode
    FROM     TOfferingBase
    GROUP BY PBillingCode
    HAVING   Count(DISTINCT OfferingSubTypeID) > 1
) THEN 'problem' ELSE 'ok' END AS durum
```

Comment: Thanks, it will wok